# Different efficiency of iterator and const_iterator (STL)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

In Qt there are similar classes to list an map. These classes provide a begin_const() method that returns a const_iterator. The documentation says that these const_iterators should be used whenever possible since they are faster.

The STL only gives you a const_iterator if the instance itself is const. Only one begin() method is implemented (overloaded for const).

**Is there any difference when read-accessing elements with iterator and const_iterator?** (I dont'w know why there's a difference for them in Qt)

Comment: When you switch from the ancient stl to the current version of the c++ standard library, you will get a cbegin function that returns const_iterators. Also note that you can assign iterators to const_iterators and that the const version of begin returns a const iterator too (all for the c++ standard library).

Comment: My reference was cplusplus.com. There is no cbegin(). Can you point me to a nice and more up to date STL reference? Now the question is even more pressing since there IS a cbegin() method...

Comment: The function that PlasmaHH is pointing is part of C++11: [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EzywvCM9/) but I don't know if there are performance issues for using iterators instead of const iterators.

Comment: @HWende: as I said in my comment, when you switch away from stl to the current c++ standard library, then you have it. stl does not have it, and since the last revision is from ~2000, it won't get it. For the c++ standard library, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map seems to be quite good these days.

Comment: @HWende to avoid confusion, the STL is not the same as the C++ standard, although the terms get mixed quite often. The bottom line is what you say is also right for C++98, C++03, but C++11 provides the methods mentioned by PlasmaHH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The documentation says that these const_iterators should be used whenever possible since they are faster.

It sure does. From http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html#stl-style-iterators:

> For each container class, there are two STL-style iterator types: one that provides read-only access and one that provides read-write access. Read-only iterators should be used wherever possible because they are faster than read-write iterators.

What a stupid thing to say.

Safer? Yes. Faster? Even if this were the case (it apparently isn't with gcc and clang), it is rarely a reason to prefer const iterators over non-const ones. This is premature optimization. The reason to prefer const iterators over non-const ones is safety. If you don't need the pointed-to contents to be modified, use a const iterator. Think of what some maintenance programmer will do to your code.

As far as `begin` versus `cbegin` is concerned, that's a C++11 addition. This allows the `auto` keyword to use a const iterator, even in a non-const setting.

Comment: So even if somehow there might be a difference in Qt I for now assume there is none in C++. I also agree to not unsing the normal/const just because of performance reason. Thanks for the clear statement!

Answer (score 3):

The best reason to use const is to avoid bugs and make the intent of the code more clear.

It's conceivable that, in some cases, the compiler could perform some optimizations that would not be possible with a non-const iterator.  Aliasing (when multiple variables and parameters may reference the same object) is often an inhibitor of some optimizations.  If the compiler could rule out some forms of aliasing by noting that the const-iterator can never change the value, then perhaps it would enable some optimizations.

On the other hand, I'd expect a compiler that's good enough to use constness in that way to be able to reach the same conclusion with flow analysis.